# Deploying Angular App on AWS for Production

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an AngularJS app which we need to deploy on production. It also has REST API calls.

As of now for development, we deployed it on AWS EC2 Ubuntu Instance and using grunt serve to run it.

I know grunt should be used only for development, so what are the other ways to deploy Angular App on AWS? I see many answers for deploying it on S3/Cloudfront. Can't we use EC2 instance with Nginx/Tomcat for this purpose on production?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use s3.

Comment: Is your backend written with NodeJS?

Comment: @Ashan no, Python.

Comment: Answers for most of the how questions depends on what you want to achieve, your SLA & cost requirements etc., without those details, no answer would be complete answer.

Comment: @Nambari I have my Angular App as well as backend ready in Python, I'm using EC2 to run both python and Angular app(running it on grunt server). I have good time to try and test AWS so i'm trying to explore better ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup CloudFront infront of EC2 instance to cache static contents in Angular App, which will improve the application performance better at scale.

If you can clearly seperate the Angular App including the index.html, it is an option to host it in AWS S3 also using CloudFront as a cache and a proxy to your EC2 instance which will reduce the overhead completely on delivering static  content from the EC2 instance, further improving the performance. Also you can use S3 to store file uploads.

Comment: I am little surprised with these CloudFront recommendations always. In my opinion whether CloudFront is required or not depends on what type of application and how much owner is willing to spend on computing costs etc.,

Comment: In AWS for S3 and CloudFront solves key problems for many solution architectures. Thats why many recommendations. Its always an option but not a must

Comment: I am not denying the fact that they solve problems, but it is debatable when we use them always & for every application. These solutions are highly dependent on what type of application and SLA requirments.